# In an EmberJS model, is there a better way to parse and bind to a json object as an attribute?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, coffeescript, ember-data

This is for parsing and binding a json object as an attribute (there's a transform as well, but it's very basic):

```
cleanCredentials: ->
  creds = @get('credentials')
  Object.keys(creds).forEach (key) =>
    unless key in @get('selectedDriver').api_keys
      delete @get('credentials')["#{key}"]

get_set: ->
  key   = arguments[0][0]
  value = arguments[0][1]
  if (arguments[0].length > 1)
    @set "credentials.#{key}", value
    @cleanCredentials()
  @get "credentials.#{key}"

getter_setter = `function(key, value) { return this.get_set(arguments); }.property('credentials')`

apiToken:          getter_setter
applicationId:     getter_setter
applicationUserId: getter_setter
companyCode:       getter_setter
username:          getter_setter
```

It works, and I understand it, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you should define custom transform:

```js
App.RawTransform = DS.Transform.extend({
  deserialize: function(json) {
    return json;
  },
  serialize: function(object) {
    return object;
  }
});

App.Model = DS.Model.extend({
  rawJSONobject: DS.attr('raw')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution won't be able to bind to individual items within the json string but will watch the entire json string... Also, haven't been able to test this, but hopefully this will give you some ideas.

```
App.Person = Ember.Model.extend({

  // json string
  'jsonData' : DS.attr('string'),

  // computed property
  'parsedData' : function(key, value) {

      // setter -- take an object and save the stringified version to the model
      if (arguments.length > 1) {
          this.set('jsonData', JSON.stringify(value));
      }

      // return the parsed json string rather than the string itself...
      return $.parseJSON(this.get('jsonData'));

  }.property('jsonData')

});
```